# Junit multiple setup and single test

Tags: java, junit

I want to write a test that perform Setup in several ways but expect them to produce the same output. Basically like

```
@Before
public void setUp1(){
    obj.addDataThisWay(data);
}

@Before
public void setUp2(){
    obj.addDataThatWay(data);
}

@Test
public void testResult(){
    assertEquals(obj.getResult(),1);
}
```

I want it the test to run twice, one for `setUp1()->testResult()`, the other one for `setUp2()->testResult()` Is that possible?

Comment: In testng you could use the @DataProvider annotation and have the setup done that way, passing in two different instances of obj. But I don't know what the junit equivalent would be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. You must either turn this into two separate tests (and extract the assertions to a common, private, non-`@Test` method if you want to), or you can use [parameterized tests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html).

Comment: I ended up with paramterized tests. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

```
public void testWithSetup1() {
     callSetup1Here();
     .....
}

public void testWithSetup2() {
     callSetup2Here();
     .....
}
```

I don't think there is any other way to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

I am just guessing now, but can't you use inheritance? creating an abstract class with your testResult() method and concrete classes with each one of the setUp() methods?

Comment: Very clever! I just did a simple test and it seems this does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

With [TestNG](http://testng.org), you would use groups for this:

```
@BeforeMethod(groups = "g1")
public void setUp1(){
  obj.addDataThisWay(data);
}

@BeforeMethod(groups = "g2")
public void setUp2(){
  obj.addDataThatWay(data);
}

@Test(groups = { "g1", "g2" })
public void testResult(){
  assertEquals(obj.getResult(),1);
}
```

If you ask TestNG to run the group "g1", it will run setUp1() -> testResult. If you run the group "g2", it will run setUp2() -> testResult.

Also, like the commenter above said, you can use data providers to pass different parameters to your test method:

```
//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
//is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };
}

//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JUnit Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) can do the trick.

Modifying the code in the original question using Parameterized should look something like the following:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTest {

    private Object obj;

    public MyTest(boolean addDataThisWay) {
        if (addDataThisWay)
            obj.addDataThisWay(data);
        else
            obj.addDataThatWay(data);
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> differentTestSettings() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {true},
            {false}
        });
    }    

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        // any additional setup required
    }

    @Test
    public void testResult(){
       assertEquals(obj.getResult(),1);
    }
}
```